# How can stop Caddy's header uncapitalize it's first letter?

Tags: http, headers

I use Caddy as a proxy server on my VPS,

and this is my Caddyfile config:

```
https://api.yuhenabc.com {
    gzip
    tls /etc/ssl/caddy/chained.crt /etc/ssl/caddy/private.key
    proxy / 127.0.0.1:5000 {
        header_downstream -Server
    }
}
```

the config is normal, you can use someothers as well,

the problem is that the header after proxy is in "lower case",

eg. "Content-Type" ==> "content-type"

So, is there a way to stop Caddy uncapitalizing the first letter?

use curl to see difference:

```
~ curl -I https://agent.yuhenabc.com/
HTTP/2 200 
accept-ranges: bytes
content-type: text/html
date: Sun, 04 Aug 2019 01:55:34 GMT
etag: "2d-573507058d0c0"
last-modified: Mon, 13 Aug 2018 12:43:23 GMT
server: Caddy
content-length: 45
```

original:

```
~ curl -I http://127.0.0.1:5000               
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 04 Aug 2019 02:19:06 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.34 (Unix) LibreSSL/2.5.5 PHP/7.1.23
Last-Modified: Mon, 13 Aug 2018 12:43:23 GMT
ETag: "2d-573507058d0c0"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 45
Content-Type: text/html
```

Answer (score 1):

This is normal.

In HTTP/1.x, header names [are case-insensitive](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2). Applications are *required* to accept `Content-Type`, `content-type`, and even `CoNtEnT-tYpE` as identical headers.

> RFC 7230: **3.2.  Header Fields**

> Each header field consists of a case-insensitive field name followed
> by a colon (":"), optional leading whitespace, the field value, and
> optional trailing whitespace.

The same applies in HTTP/2, but additionally headers are *always* [sent as lowercase](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-8.1.2) according to the specification. Because cURL and Caddy both support HTTP/2 and use it whenever possible, you will always see all-lowercase headers – anything else would violate the protocol's spec.

> RFC 7540: **8.1.2.  HTTP Header Fields**

> Just as in HTTP/1.x, header field names are strings of ASCII
> characters that are compared in a case-insensitive fashion.  However,
> header field names MUST be converted to lowercase prior to their
> encoding in HTTP/2.  A request or response containing uppercase
> header field names MUST be treated as malformed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're feeling really, but really brave, you can create a new GOROOT with Golang 1.19.5 and replace those four files into it with the ones from [this Golang fork I made](https://github.com/porech/go/tree/case-insensitive-headers):

- src/net/http/header.go
- src/net/http/request.go
- src/net/http/server.go
- src/net/textproto/reader.go

Then, build Caddy using xcaddy pointing to your GOROOT:

```
GOROOT=/home/porech/my-custom-goroot/go1.19.5 XCADDY_WHICH_GO=/home/porech/my-custom-goroot/go1.19.5/bin/go xcaddy build
```

I was desperate and I absolutely needed this, and I advice you to do so only if you're in the same situation. I'm using it in production and it works, but there may be important side-effects I'm unaware of!

Comment: Why the hell would you even need this?! In HTTP/2 header names lowercase, what's wrong with the current behavior of Caddy?!

Comment: @AradAlvand Caddy is doing nothing wrong, I never said this. But others are doing things wrong, and that's something you need to deal with sometimes. Specifically, some audio players (and I'm talking about the Alexa Echo Dot embedded player, not something underground) don't consider Icy-Metaint in the response headers, but only a lowercase "icy-metaint". Their fault? Yes. Is this causing choppy playback on the radio station skills? You bet it does. Should Amazon address this? Yes. Will they do? For now I've been ignored :) see https://shorturl.at/knMUZ

Comment: Just to clarify: Echo Dot uses HTTP/1.1 so Caddy "canonicalizes" the header names, with the first letter capitalized.

Comment: Ah okay, I see, that's understandable then. That really is a blatant bug on their side. HTTP headers have **always** been case-insensitive; that's not even something new or specific to HTTP/2, it's just outright wrong to check header names case-sensitively, so that's pretty stupid of them honestly... Hopefully they'll fix it soon so you won't have to deal with forking freaking Golang.